# Find a folder with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to find a specific folder in a batch file where I can't use the `if exist` command as I don't know exactly where the file is located. I can find files with this:

```
    For /R D:\ %%G IN (*.ut2) do Echo "%%G"
```

I'd like to find the file's folder or modify the output to a variable where it leaves off the file name and only the folder it is located in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `%%~dp` prefix for your loop variable to get a full folder path of the file:

```
For /R D:\ %%G IN (*.ut2) do Echo Folder is "%%~dpG"
```